# Can I receive some account ban advice?

Tags: support, post-ban

Would anybody be able to take a look at my account and let me know what I should fix? I've undeleted my questions (originally though deleting bad questions would be helpful)and added missing code to questions.

I am still not very experienced, so I have trouble answering other questions. Any advice on what other reasons I probably got banned or good advice for early-stage coders on here to survive would be awesome. I'm digging the fast-paced community, but need guidance. Thanks!

Comment: As always, so nice to see people trying to learn the ropes and become great members of the community. Keep overflowing!

Comment: Refreshing to see someone ready to work on his/her previous questions to get unbanned, rather than coming to meta and cry..

Comment: I misread title of the question and thought it's some moderator asking, "Can I receive some _account ban device_?"

Comment: @gnat And I thought it was "can I recieve some account ban *twice*" clearly some trickery going on here

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As someone in the comments on this post mentioned, [CSS works with FF and IE, but not Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594962/css-works-with-ff-and-ie-but-not-chrome), you need to *ask a question*. It's not clear what the problem is or what the outcome is you hope to achieve.

I upvoted the question here, [CSS Header Background-Color Won't Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606963/css-header-background-color-wont-work), as it has some value due to the id/class issue. id attributes should never be repeated in the same HTML doc as they are designed to be unique. So if you say id="header" you can't use id="header" elsewhere on the page.

With that said, a lot of your questions are unclear and border on showing no research effort on your part, and that isn't just something that the community uses to harass folks, seeing what you've tried is critical to helping potential answerers get a head start in helping you solve the problem building upon the foundation you provide initially. I think it's clear that you *have* tried to solve the problems yourself and that you're very new to HTML, so I'd suggest focusing on highlighting what you've tried, what didn't work, and what you expect to happen so answerers don't have waste energy guessing what you're trying to do and instead can put that energy towards helping you. In other words, [help me, help you!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGt5f70K02Q)

As far as posting goes, if you can't post questions, find some posts you can significantly edit. Perhaps you'll come across a question with some severe formatting problems that you can make a *significant* suggested edit to. These actions will help you circumvent the ban.

I'll leave you with these two points, since you're new:

- First, consider that any problem you're currently facing has more than likely already been asked and answered by others. Thus, strive to improve your search skills. Learn how to conduct your searches, both on Google and Stack Overflow, so that you can find existing questions that describe your problem so that you can find answers *without* posting. The ban is designed to eliminate noise, and if you're asking questions that have already been answered, you're not helping improve Stack Overflow.
- Second, don't let anyone tell you that you can't give back to communities such as Stack Overflow, even if that's just something you're thinking in your own head. Asking good technical questions is a skill, and if you can formulate your *unique* questions -- those that haven't already been asked/answered -- in a manner that's clear, that helps not just you but also others who visit this site, that is how *you* give back to the community.  Question askers are just as important as question answerers, and if you put good effort into your questions, know that the reward you gain is that you've helped others who lack the ability to ask good questions.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: That is great advice! Thanks!

Comment: Great and thorough answer; needs more upvotes :P +1

Answer (score 5):

To start with I would recommend further editing, remove things like "thanks", "Any help would be epic", and "I know this is probably one simple mistake I'm missing, but a second set of eyes would be great."  from your posts, it may seem odd, but unnecessary pleasantries should be avoided.

Next flesh your questions out a little, if you're having a problem describe exactly what the problem is.

Don't rely on links, jsFiddle is good for an additional resource, but your posts need to be able to stand on their own. If jsFiddle's server goes down your posts could become unanswerable.

**And lastly and probably most importantly research, research, research.**

Research, before you ask, and research even more before you answer.

Try going through some of the older unanswered questions, find one that interests you and research the hell out of it and post a good answer, chances are you'll get a least a couple up-votes.

Comment: Not only could the posts become unanswerable if the links break, but they won't help others with the same problem, as they won't be able to *see* they have the same problem. All in all, these are excellent points! :)

Comment: @jmort253 thanks. Not nearly as complete as your answer though

Answer (score 4):

[Your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17594962) looks okay; it has no downvotes (nor upvotes), so the community didn't really think it was that great a question, but it wasn't *that* bad either. You might want to change your question a little bit to say that you started out with one stylesheet, changed it, and Chrome kept using the previous one if that's actually what happened. That might make it a bit more clear that it was a caching issue.

Your other questions have a few more problems. Where possible, you should reduce your code to the minimal amount that still demonstrates the problem. [This question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17645565), for example, has quite a bit of code that probably doesn't directly relate to your problem. For example, I doubt that rotator script had anything to do with the spacing, given the answer. If you still experience the same problem after removing something, maybe that thing wasn't relevant to the question and should be removed. In [this question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606963), there are irrelevant things, too, like the `font-family` declaration.

In short:

- Reduce your code to a [short, self contained, runnable, example](http://www.sscce.org/).
- After reducing your test case to be as simple as possible, include as much detail as would be necessary to reproduce the problem.