# Can we have some statistics about users who could overcome the post-ban?

Tags: support, statistics, post-ban

We often come across questions on Meta where users complaint/rant that they can't ask/answer any further question; some come here for advice on how to overcome this restriction and re-juvenate their user accounts like the following one:

- [Can I receive some account ban advice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189077/can-i-receive-some-account-ban-advice)

So, can we have some statistics about how many users are getting banned on a periodic basis and how many of them are able to recover and overcome this ban, what was the extent of effort required on their part to recover from this ban (amount of upvotes they had to receive, edit suggestions they had to made, etc), time period taken to overcome and other similar statistics which would help to assess the situation?

Comment: You're not very likely to get an answer to the "extent of effort required" I'd say. Other than that, I seem to remember Shog9 once answering something similar before?

Comment: @Bart: I understand some of those statistics would be difficult to dig-into... I am more concerned about how many percentage of people are actually able to overcome this ban... any other related statistic is always welcome... As far as Shog9 answering something similar before - I didn't see it, hopefully someone would be able to guide to that post :)

Comment: Ah, here we go: [What happens to folks who get question banned, by and large?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172300/what-happens-to-folks-who-get-question-banned-by-and-large)...so I guess this would be a duplicate..