# Statistics about people who have recovered from their question ban

Tags: discussion, statistics, post-ban

I've [asked](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7807/15479) this question on Stack Overflow in Russian, but our CM told me to ask this question here.

I've found only a few similar posts:

- [Can we have some statistics about users who could overcome the post-ban?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189313/260198)
- [What happens to folks who get question banned, by and large?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172300/260198)

As you can see from @Shog9 answer:

> Most folks who've encountered a q-ban haven't done much of anything
>   afterwards

The system doesn't work well.

For people who don't understand, the main purpose of such restriction actions (post ban, etc.) is to teach people and help them to reform. It's not about blocking members as primary intention.

But in its current realization it looks like real-life prison, which should help people, re-educate them, but, in fact, makes things worse.

Few things:

1. Can we have some statistics about users who were post-banned, percent of those people who has released their bans?
2. I assume that nothing changed from 2013, and most of those people have been lost forever. So, logical question, do you see the problem here? You have to analyze this data (otherwise, all this thing doesn't matter at all), so are you planning to improve ban system?

Comment: Keep in mind that in 2013 there were no warnings or short rate limits in advance of a ban; one would just get banned without warning.

Comment: This is an anecdote, not data, but it seems to me to indicate that the system is working just fine:  There is a user I've seen on a couple sites I frequent and on several more where I read and lurk a little bit who has been Q banned on multiple sites.  Despite repeated explanations of why their questions are badly received (by many people across multiple sites), they continue to ask similar questions on the sites where they aren't banned, and are unable to improve their questions on sites where they are banned.  This particular person _shouldn't_ be allowed to post questions ==> it works!

Comment: @Ward on Russian StackOverflow I've seen only few people over the last years who have recovered their bans.

Comment: 'Most folks' it's not clear whether Shoddy means 'Most users' or 'Most accounts'.  Many users just open new accounts when banned and carry on with their homework dumps etc.

Comment: It is fair to say to really fresh users (not the ones that created yet another account) don't go from *all is fine* to *q-ban* instantly. They do get quality warnings upfront. If you even want to start making a point about prisons and such, please also ask to include the stats of users that have been shown a q-ban warning and recovered from those. I really think the majority of the cases that actually hit a full q-ban will be similar to what @ward describes and I don't think the system needs adjustment to cater for those, whatever the stats will learn us.

Comment: Unlike real-life prisons, there are plenty of other places users can go to after receiving a ban. If they don't want to be here, and we don't want them here, why try to force it? If anything, I'd say the problem is with the process up to this point, as in to help users *avoid* a ban. A ban *is* severe and *should* be hard to recover from - that's the point - if users reach that point, they need to put in some effort to show they actually want to be here and understand the rules and will follow them.

Comment: @Dukeling I don't understand where thoughts that "they don't want to be here" come from. They want, but they can't. New members don't know that they will be punished for questions with negative score. 1st of all, they don't understand rules when they come here. And most of the time they don't understand why their questions were downvoted. After some time the get it, but it's to late. And when they got banned, they just leave, 'cause they feel betrated. I've talked with such people, after ban they don't want to write something anymore, they feel devastated.

Comment: @Suvitruf I mean, someone who got banned asked a bunch of questions that don't belong here and probably got frustrated by having their questions downvoted and closed. At that point you have to wonder whether they want to be **here**, or whether they rather want to be somewhere that would be more accepting of their questions. But, like I said above, we need do more to help users **before** they get banned, not make the ban less severe.

Comment: @Dukeling "we need do more to help users before they get banned" totally agree.

Comment: @Suvitruf That's why they get warned before they are banned. They are given links explaing what they can do to avoid and get out of a ban. If they rather leave instead of working on their contribution, it is their choice.

Comment: _"The system doesn't work well. For people who don't understand, the main purpose of such restriction actions (post ban, etc.) is to teach people and help them to reform. It's not about blocking members as primary intention."_ I don't think that's the intention at all. Stack Exchange would prefer that this people just go away and pollute some other site with their drek. For those that are _willing_ to do the work to redeem their accounts, there is at least a path to do that.